# Trying to write a function to shuffle a deck in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, shuffle

So all I'm trying to do is take an input from the user of how many cards to use and then randomly assign each card to a different index in an array.  I'm having extensive issues getting the rand function to work properly.  I've done enough reading to find multiple different ways of shuffling elements in an array to find this one to be the easiest in regards to avoiding duplicates.  I'm using GCC and after I input the amount of cards I never get the values from the array back and if I do they're all obscenely large numbers.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int d, c, i, z, l, r;
    printf("Enter the deck length: ");
    scanf("%d\n ", &c);
    int deck[c];
    int swap[c];
    z = c;
    for(l=0; l<c; l++){
            swap[l] = l;
            }
    for(i=z; i=0; i--){
            r = rand() / i 
            deck[i] = swap[r];
                    for(r; r=(c-1); r++){   
                    swap[r] = swap[(r+1)];
                    }
            }
    for(d = 0; d < c; d++){
            printf("%d ", deck[d]);
            }
    return;
    }
```

Comment: This portion of your code doesn't look right: for(r; r=(c-1); r++), what is the starting value for r?

Comment: If you turn on compiler hints and warnings, it would tell you immediately where to look for the problem.

Comment: The return type for main should be int (not void), then at the bottom you should have return (some int value);

Comment: Google "Fisher-Yates"; that's the correct (and much simpler) way to shuffle a list.

Comment: @roybatty - _what is the starting value for r?_  ***It is alway*** equal to `r = rand() / i`  (just look up two lines)

Answer (score 0):

I can spot one major problem here:

```
for(i=z; i=0; i--)
         ^^^
```

This loop will never execute since you are using assignment(`=`) and setting `i` to `0` therefore the condition will always be *false*, although using equality(`==`) will still be *false* in this case, you probably want:

```
for(i=z; i!=0; i--)
```

This means you will be using `deck` unitialized which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once you fix that you have a similar problems here:

```
for(r; r=(c-1); r++){
```

`main` has to return `int` and your `return` at the end needs to provide a value.

Turning on warning should have allowed you to find most of these issues, for example using `-Wall` with `gcc` gives me the following warning for both `for` loops:

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

Note, see [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) for guidelines on how to use `rand` properly.

Answer (score -2):

You basically need to be able to generate 52 numbers pseudo-randomly, without repeating.  Here is a way to do that...

First, loop a random number generator 52 times, with a method to ensure none of the *random* numbers repeat.  Two functions in addition to the main() will help to do this:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int NotUsedRecently (int number);
int randomGenerator(int min, int max);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<52;i++)
    {
        printf("Card %d :%d\n",i+1, randomGenerator(1, 52));
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;   
}
int randomGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random=0, trying=0;

    trying = 1;         
    while(trying)
    {

        srand(clock());
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        ((random >= min)&&(NotUsedRecently(random))) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }

    return random;
}

int NotUsedRecently (int number)
{
    static int recent[1000];//make sure this index is at least > the number of values in array you are trying to fill 
    int i,j;
    int notUsed = 1;

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0]));i++)  (number != recent[i]) ? (notUsed==notUsed) : (notUsed=0, i=(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0])));
    if(notUsed) 
    {
        for(j=(sizeof(recent)/sizeof(recent[0]));j>1;j--)
        {
            recent[j-1] = recent[j-2];
        }
        recent[j-1] = number;
    }
    return notUsed;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, you're reseeding the prng on every call? And reseeding from [a timer function with no resolution guarantees](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html)?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson - Yes, Seriously, And with no apologies.  Look at the function `NotUsedRecently()`.  Because of the time delay of that function, and what it does, this combination works great.  Have used it (and variations) for years successfully.  I _Purposely_ call `srand(clock())` each time _Because_ of that fact. (it gets re-seeded each time) ***You might try it out before you judge it***.  I originally designed it to guarantee a set of ***unique*** - pseudo random numbers to populate a variable sized array.  I would appreciate your comments _once_ you have tried it.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson - Also, Fisher-Yates not withstanding, because of the uniqueness guarantee provided by the support function NotUsedRecently(), the algorithm I used in the above works well to randomly assign each card to a different index in an array per OP request.  ***The one thing I would concede*** to would be to move the srand(clock) function out of the `while()` loop.  Although its not necessary because of its context, when I see your answer here, I will do that. :)